# flask dyanmo query for count fileds

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-dynamodb

consider this schema in dyanmo db,we count of question

```
[
    {
        'TableName': "user_detail",
        'KeySchema': [
            {'AttributeName': "timestamp", 'KeyType': "HASH"},
            {'AttributeName': "question", 'KeyType': "RANGE"},
        ],
        'AttributeDefinitions': [
            {'AttributeName': "timestamp", 'AttributeType': "S"},
            {'AttributeName': "question", 'AttributeType': "N"},
        ],
        'ProvisionedThroughput': {
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 40,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 40]            }
    }
]
```

I'm beginner of dyanmo db can any one give idea for that one.we need query,the sql query goes like that `select count(question) from user_detail where question =1`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will throw some pointers. DynamoDB has two types of APIs :-

**Option 1:-**

1) Scan API - will scan the whole table. The scan api should be used when the hash key value is not known

2) Query API - will query the table using hash key. The hash key is must for Query API

In your case, the hash key value is not known. So, you can't use Query API. However, you can use scan API which is a very costly operation in terms of performance and cost. So, it should be avoided if you have a table of millions of items.

The alternative is to create **global secondary index (GSI)** with `question` attribute as hash key and some other field as sort key (possibly `timestamp`). This way, you should be able to use Query API on GSI. However, this wouldn't solve the problem completely.

DynamoDB doesn't have aggregate functions like count,min and max. So, you need to count the number of items in the result set at client side.

**Option 2:-**

If you have an option to change the data model, you can redesign the above table as mentioned below:-

```
question - hash key
timestamp - range key
```

I have seen many use cases using `timestamp` as range key. Please analyse your query access patterns (QAP) for all your use cases and make the decision accordingly.